# Spotting the N1 に N2 construction (eg パンにバター）

Tags: word-choice

I have recently come to the conclusion that the N1 に N2 construction (eg パンにバター）is more common than I thought. It is the only explanation I think of to make grammatical sense of the sentences below. Could somebody confirm I have this right (**in bold**)  in the following case?

> なお、**本状と行き違いにお支払い済み**の場合はお許しください
>   Please ignore this notice if you have already paid (this card and your payment have crossed)

*Note*

The following sentence has been removed as に should have been の：**相手に言い分**もわかったとはいえ、心から納得したわけではない ( "Although I understand were he's coming from, I can't really agree with him.")

Comment: What does Sentence 1 mean? I think that it doesn't make sense. Who is the subject of 分かった? What you considered as the N1 に N2 construction is usually a phrase with omission of a verb. パンにバターをぬる makes パンにバター, which comes from パンにぬる and バターをぬる.

Comment: 「相手"に"言い分"も"」→「相手"の"言い分"は"」？

Comment: comment 1: Chocolate & Hyperworm are quite right, it should be の. I checked the source. Thanks. This sentence now makes sense.

Comment: Comment 2: @Gradius This use of に is still a problem for me. I've made a new question to keep things clean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not an instance of the listing に.

Here に indicates that (と)行き違い describes the manner in which お支払い(済み) was done.

> Please forgive us in the case that payment has been completed "in crossing" with this letter. (=while the letter was still on its way... I'm not sure you can use this form for this in English, I might just have made "in crossing" up)

I think it's the same as this に, despite お支払い済み appearing not to be a verb...

> And ringing the bell in passing, he led the way into the adjoining room.
>   そして通りすがりに鐘をならしつつ、かれは隣室へと一同を先導した。

Comment: Comment3(contd from above): @Hyperworm: Tx: This is grammar I can't find in text books, hence the guesses. Can に act as a adverb with verbs such as those above and perhaps 擦れ違い or is this possibly a variation on 「本を買いに行く」

Comment: I have removed sentence one from my question. I shall probably put my new questions into a new one, with an appropriate q-title, you can get the credit for this one. Tx