# Making sense of the N1にN2 construction (「パンにバター」＝「パンにバターをぬる」）

Tags: grammar, usage, particle-に

I understand from [my previous question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6596) on the N1 に N2 construction that it is usually a phrase with omission of a verb (eg パンにバターをぬる makes パンにバター, which comes from パンにぬる and バターをぬる). If this is the case then how can we apply this logic to the following sentences?:

> 1. 日本の朝食といえば、ご飯にお味噌汁でしょう
>      When you talk about Japanese breakfast, rice and miso shiru must come in to the pcture.
> 2. 私は、家ではたいていジーンズにTシャツを着ています。
>      I mostly wear jeans and T-shirt around the house.

My text book’s explanation of both these sentences is 「N1とN2の組み合わせ」which might work in the same way as:

> セーターとスカートを組み合わせる｜match a sweater [and a skirt / with a skirt]

But this does seem as good as パンにバターをぬる. The best I can come up with is changing にto　と in sentences 1 & 2 as follows:

> 4. 日本の朝食といえば、ご飯とお味噌汁を食べるでしょう。
> 5. 私は、家ではたいていジーンズとTシャツを着ています。

Reference: 総まとめ　文法 N1 p110 (I have not managed to find any other references to this.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem: if you're already saying `N1にN2` "usually" implies the omission of a verb, then doesn't that mean this case you're trying to apply that logic to may not fit that case?  So...maybe *don't* try to apply that logic to those sentences.

Your textbook seems to be describing this use of に as listing items that go together.

The same way the classic American breakfast, "bacon and eggs", is a set, so is "rice and miso shiru", and in Japanese, using に to list them instead of と specifically implies that they "go together" (a la "bacon and eggs").  Likewise, "a t-shirt and jeans" is a fairly common set.

So yes, when に is used for listing, you can basically just substitute と for に, but you're also losing a bit of nuance if you think they're exactly the same.

Edit:

The huge difference between `パンにバター(をぬる)` and `N1にN2 (=組み合わせ)` is that, in the former, パン and バター have different roles, as the indirect object and the direct object respectively; in the latter, both N1 and N2 have the same role (the object, in your sample 2; I'm not sure what you call whatever comes before a copula).

To think of it another way, in your sample sentences, you can substitute a phrase like "these things" for `N1にN2` and the sentence remains basically equivalent.  But since パン and バター are playing different roles, you can't substitute a single phrase for パンにバター and get an equivalent sentence.

Comment: Thank you, I've reworded the question, please take a look - i am trying to tie down the nuance you refer to.

Comment: @Tim I expanded the answer with why the bread/butter example is a false parallel.  Otherwise, I'm not sure how I can help you understand better. =/  If you ask me, the "nuance" is just that N1 and N2 form a set, of things that usually go together.

Comment: Thank you - you've made the difference quite clear. I was looking for something that does not exist but I see that now.